# How to create a road map like Candy Crush’s roadmap dashboard for Android app?

Tags: android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/psiHL.jpg)I want create a display like that image I uplooaded? What are techniques which I can use for my app?

I tried use a dynamic background on android studio but it's not feasible? Can someone help me? Can you give me some Instructional videos

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think I can help you much, I'll just give you an idea. 
If you are going to draw it programatically, you might try drawing the map curves using bezier curve in canvas, such tutorial can be found here https://medium.com/@kezhang404/either-compose-is-elegant-or-if-you-want-to-draw-something-with-an-android-view-you-have-to-7ce00dc7cc1
For the level button, you may add some clicker listener to the canvas, check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68363029/how-to-add-click-events-to-canvas-in-jetpack-compose