# Making Compose Canvas drawables Clickable

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I'm building a `UI` in `Jetpack Compose` using `Canvas` to draw custom visuals. I want to enable click interaction on any element I draw, including shapes like `drawRect` and `drawCircle`, but also arbitrary paths, images, and potentially even other composables embedded within the canvas.

I've explored these options:

- `Modifier.clickable` on Canvas: This triggers clicks anywhere on the canvas, not individual elements.

My goal is to detect clicks on any drawn element and trigger specific actions based on that element. Any advice or code samples for achieving this clickability would be incredibly helpful!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add click events to Canvas in JetPack Compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68363029/how-to-add-click-events-to-canvas-in-jetpack-compose)

Comment: it might, but i can not iterate in my shapes because they could be a lot